# Toggling input value angularjs

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I'm creating grocery list app in angularjs. And here is my problem. [CodePen](http://codepen.io/biaggio12/pen/XNJWGG)

While i pick an item from list of categories it highlight my Category icons, it does not happen in reverse. Tried many different solutions and can't seem to get it work.

Im sorry, but i couldn't get to work snippet here. I just posted it because i couldn't post other way. The working one is at CodePen

```js
angular.module('MyApp',['ngMaterial'])
    .controller('ItemsCtrl',function($scope){
        $scope.amounts = ('1kg 2kg 3kg 4kg 5kg '+'1szt 2szt 3szt 4szt 5szt 6szt 7szt '+'1l 2l 3l 4l 5l').split(' ').map(function(amount){
            return {abbrev: amount};
        });
        $scope.items = [

        ];
        $scope.categoriesObj = [
            {
            name:'Vegetables',
            img:'img/noun_75334_cc.svg'
            },
            {
                name:'Vegetables',
                img:'img/noun_75333_cc.svg'
            },
            {
                name:'Fruits',
                img:'img/noun_75334_cc.svg'
            },
            {
                name:'Chemistry',
                img:'img/noun_75335_cc.svg'
            },
            {
                name:'Drinks',
                img:'img/noun_75336_cc.svg'
            },
            {
                name:'Alcohol',
                img:'img/noun_75337_cc.svg'
            }
        ];


        $scope.pushItem = function(name,amount,category){
            $scope.items.push(
                {
                    name:name,
                    amount:amount,
                    category:category
                }
            )
        };

        $scope.selectItem = function (item){
            $scope.category = item;

        };
        $scope.selectedIndex = -1; // Whatever the default selected index is, use -1 for no selection

        $scope.itemClicked = function ($index) {
            $scope.selectedIndex = $index;
        };

    });
```

```css
html,body {
    font-family: 'Roboto', sans-serif;
    font-size: 16px;
    height:100%;
    margin:0;
    padding: 0;
}
md-toolbar h3 {
    margin:auto;
    font-weight: 700;
}

md-list-item > button {
    width:100%;
    font-weight: 700;
    text-align: left;
}
.btn1 {
    background-color: lightgreen;
}

.avatar {
    position: relative;
    width: 128px;
    height: 128px;
    border-radius: 50%;
    border: 1px solid #ddd;
    display: inline-block;
    overflow: hidden;
    margin: 0px;
    vertical-align: middle;
    zoom: 1;
    transform: translateZ(1);
    -webkit-transform: scale(1);
    -moz-transform: scale(1);
}
.category {
    padding:20px 10px 0px 10px;
    width:150px;
    height: 150px;
    display: inline-block;
    float: left;
    border-radius: 50%;
    border: 1px solid #ddd;
}
.category:hover {
    -webkit-transform: scale(1.4);
    border: 1px solid lightblue;
}

.category:first-child {
    margin-left: 30px;
}
ul {
    list-style-type: none;
}
.selected {
    border: 3px solid #000;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.23/angular.min.js"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angular_material/1.1.0/angular-material.min.css">
<body ng-app="MyApp" layout="column">
<md-toolbar>
    <h1>Grocery List Application</h1>
</md-toolbar>
<div class="container" layout="row" flex ng-controller="ItemsCtrl">
    <md-sidenav md-is-locked-open="true" class="md-whiteframe-4dp">
        <md-list>
            <md-list-item ng-repeat="categories in categoriesObj">
                <md-button>
                    <md-icon md-svg-src="{{ categories.img }}" class="avatar"></md-icon>
                    <h2>{{ categories.name }}</h2>
                </md-button>
            </md-list-item>
        </md-list>
    </md-sidenav>
    <md-content id="content" class="lightgreen" flex >
        <md-input-container class="md-icon-float md-block"  layout="row" layout-align="center center" flex-offset="25" >
            <label >What to add?</label>
            <input flex="30" flex-order="1" ng-model="name" type="text">
            <md-button flex="60" flex-order="2" md-no-ink class="md-primary btn1" ng-click="pushItem(name,amount,category)">Add Item to List</md-button>
        </md-input-container>
        <md-input-container class="md-block" flex-gt-sm layout="row" layout-align="center center" flex-offset="25" >
            <label>Amount</label>
            <md-select flex="30" flex-order="1" ng-model="amount">
                <md-option ng-repeat="amount in amounts" value="{{amount.abbrev}}">
                    {{amount.abbrev}}
                </md-option>
            </md-select>
        </md-input-container>
        <md-input-container class="md-block" flex-gt-sm layout="row" layout-align="center center" flex-offset="25" >
            <label>Amount</label>
            <md-select flex="30" flex-order="1" ng-model="category">
                <md-option  ng-click="itemClicked($index)" ng-repeat="category in categoriesObj" value="{{category.name}}">
                    {{category.name}}
                </md-option>
            </md-select>
        </md-input-container>

        <md-list flex layout="row">
            <md-list-item ng-click="itemClicked($index)" ng-repeat="categories in categoriesObj" ng-model="category">
                <img ng-class="{ 'selected': $index == selectedIndex }" class="category" ng-src="{{categories.img}}">
            </md-list-item>
        </md-list>

        {{categories}}
        {{thumb}}

    </md-content>
</div>

<!-- Angular Material requires Angular.js Libraries -->
<script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.5.5/angular-animate.min.js"></script>
<script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.5.5/angular-aria.min.js"></script>
<script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.5.5/angular-messages.min.js"></script>

<!-- Angular Material Library -->
<script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angular_material/1.1.0/angular-material.min.js"></script>
```

Answer (score 0):

I found a solution. Changed model on thumbnails,

```
<md-input-container class="md-block" flex-gt-sm layout="row" layout-align="center center" flex-offset="25" >
        <label>Category</label>
        <md-select flex="30" flex-order="1" ng-model="category">
            <md-option ng-click="itemClicked($index)" ng-repeat="category in categoriesObj" value="{{category.name}}">
                {{category.name}}
            </md-option>
        </md-select>
    </md-input-container>

    <md-list flex layout="row">
        <md-list-item ng-click="thumbClicked(thumb.name);itemClicked($index)" ng-repeat="thumb in categoriesObj" ng-model="thumb">
            <img ng-class="{ 'selected': $index == selectedIndex }" class="category" ng-src="{{thumb.img}}">
        </md-list-item>
    </md-list>
```

and wrote another function to update category model.

```
        $scope.thumbClicked = function(name){
        $scope.category = name;
    };
```